# XCode 4 pinwheeling while trying to debug

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, debugging

It seems whenever I go to use the debugger in my project xcode decides to get caught and shows the pinwheel indefinitely. (haven't waited more than 5 minutes.) The strange thing is that this is only happening with one of my projects, the other ones are working fine. I can mouse over a variable and it will give me the information and everything, but in my one application, not such luck.

Is there a programming error that would cause such an issue? Or is there a possible solution to this problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is it just debugger or normal too? If it's both it may be an infinite loop in your program... but debugger usually crashes then (at least for me). If it's only when debugging, maybe you haven't set it to automatically run after debugger is attached or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly have no clue what the problem was, it stopped doing it all of a sudden, then I did an update to xcode and it has not done it since. It probably just caught a hitch somewhere. whatever. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there might be an infinite loop somewhere... Otherwise I have no clue. Try rebooting your Mac. Try simulator versus device.